# C# Properties - Getting the compile time defaults

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using the "Setting" feature of C# and Visual Studio to manage my application settings. These can, of course, be overidden by XML.

However, I'd like a way to retrieve the compile-time defaults that I've set in Visual Studio

```
Properties.Settings.Defaults.MyProp
```

Does not achieve this - it returns whatever it's picked up from the XML. Is there a way to guarantee retrieving whatever was typed into the "Settings" page during development?

The context is that some of my settings are quite specific and so my application validates them to ensure they're within parameters, and I'd like to be able to fail back to defaults if not.

Comment: Have you tried `Properties.Settings.Default.Reset()`? Or are you looking for individual property resets?

Comment: @RonBeyer Yes, I could do with it on an individual basis

Comment: @Dan I believe whenever any changes are saved to the properties xml file for a user scope field, its saved to the local Apps folder while the original remains unchanged. Are you asking how to read the original xml? Also, if your app is already validating parameters, why isn't the default stored in code?

Comment: You can have multiple settings files in one application. You're just using the `Default` one. You can also create a class to use as the setting `Provider` (a Setting's `Provider` property). A custom Provider can handle a single setting. You can also mirror User settings in the Application scope. See [How to: Create Application Settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-application-settings) (and related Docs on the left),  [Making Application Settings Portable](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1238550/Making-Application-Settings-Portable)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is the only route to get the original, compile time value of the property. It's a shame that it's not strongly typed

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Properties["name"].DefaultValue as string;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Settings` type is just an auto-generated `internal sealed partial class`, so there isn't any reason you couldn't add a new `static` property called `Defaults` which did what you wanted.

```
// In some file, perhaps called Settings.Defaults.cs?
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace YourApplication.Properties
{
   internal sealed partial class Settings
   {
      public static SettingsDefaults Defaults
      {
         get { return _defaults; }
      }

      internal class SettingsDefaults
      {
         public int NumberBetween1And100
         {
            get
            {
               // Or just hardcode it and come here and change it if you change the default value.
               return (int)Settings.Default.Properties["NumberBetween1And100"].DefaultValue;
            }
         }
      }

      private static readonly SettingsDefaults _defaults = new SettingsDefaults();
   }
}
```

You could use it like you described in your question: `Properties.Settings.Defaults.NumberBetween1And100`.

It's not perfect. For example, if you add a new setting from the Settings Designer, you have to remember to come in to this file and add the new property to the `SettingsDefaults` class. Also, `Properties.Settings.Default` and `Properties.Settings.Defaults` are named so similar that it feels likely to be a source of bugs.